# Anyway to make EnsureVisible() in a TreeNode on treeView not to scroll down automatic?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two method that i'm using to search through a TreeNode in child nodes:

```
private void FindByText()
        {
            TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;
            foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
            {
                FindRecursive(n);
            }
        }
```

And the FindRecursive:

```
foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
            {
                string result = Regex.Replace(tn.Text, @"^\d*\.\s*", string.Empty);
                if (tn.Text.Contains(this.txtNodeTextSearch.Text))
                {
                    tn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    tn.EnsureVisible();
                    count++;
                    label11.Text = count.ToString();
                }

                FindRecursive(tn);
            }
```

txtNodeTextSearch is a textBox

The searching is working the problem is that if it found more then one item in any node then this line:

```
tn.EnsureVisible();
```

Weill make the treeView1 to automatic scroll down to the last found item. Then i need to scroll manualy up to see the first found items.
Is there anyway to make that it will move to the found items like EnsureVisible() but to the top one first and the one in the bottom ?

I tried to do this:

```
private void FindRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
        {
                for (int i = treeNode.Nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    TreeNode tn = treeNode.Nodes[i];
                    string result = Regex.Replace(tn.Text, @"^\d*\.\s*", string.Empty);
                    if (tn.Text.Contains(this.txtNodeTextSearch.Text))
                    {
                        tn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                        tn.EnsureVisible();
                        count++;
                        label11.Text = count.ToString();
                    }

                    FindRecursive(tn);
                }
        }
```

But it didn't change anything still it's scrolling down automatic to the last found item. Or maybe the first found item is in the bottm it dosen't matter i want that it will point/focus on the top found item and then if i want to see the other found items i will scroll down manualy.

Comment: Self-inflicted pain, your FindByText() method iterates forward so will make the *last* match visible.  Fix this properly by adding a `ref bool foundOne` argument to FindRecursive().

Comment: Hans i just did in the FindByText method instead foreach: for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)  and it's working, is that wrong ? And do i need yet a bool ? I didn't understand how to add/use the ref bool